# Transforming a NSString @"123" in an (short)array[] = {1, 2, 3}?

Tags: objective-c, c, string, parsing, math

I can't imagine a "clean" or efficient method of doing this.

I would like to transform a string of numbers like @"1234" into an array of shorts for a calculator pet project*.

I think of getting substrings and then the intValue of the substring but it sounds cumbersome and overkill. Would there be a more elegant way of doing it?

Thanks in advance!

* I know that there are more efficient ways to do maths and plenty of C libraries do this but it's for my own education :-).

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to do?  Why do you need to break the individual digits apart?  That is, why do you want an array `1, 2, 3, 4`, instead of just the number `1234`?

Comment: I want to represent them internally this way so I can do some simple operation like base transform easily. Will also allow me to control rounding perfectly (not guessing what the computer will give me). In short, I am trying to emulate an ALU. (Self education I said :-))

Comment: not sure if this is any help, but I would take characters using characterAtIndex, or better, from the `UTF8String`, and then doing it C style, `int i = c-'0';`

Comment: Are the numbers strictly positive, or is something like "123-45" (to represent 1,2,3,-4,5) possible?

Comment: Yes Steve, they are strictly positive. The int i = c-'0' was what I was looking for. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have this straight, you want to turn an NSString into a short array?  This function assumes each character in the NSString is a separate short.  Oh, and don't forget to free that array when you're done with it!

```
//Stephen Melvin <jinksys@gmail.com>
short *NSStringToShortArray(NSString *digits){

    int count = [digits length];

    short *shortArray = malloc(sizeof(short)*count);

    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
        shortArray[i] = (short)[digits characterAtIndex:i] - '0';
    }

    return shortArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good calculator interface should take one string of characters as a single number then after the operation is selected it clears the field to accept the next number.

For example.

You type in 2 then hit the * button, the field clears and you type in 2 again and press = and get 4.

If you want the interface to accept an equation or a script then you should read up on parsing numeric equations.

Comment: I am sorry Matt but I disagree. A good calculator interface will let the user type "23.34 * 23 * ( 34 + 45 )" and gives the answer. 

In your idea, user will have to type Enter a couple of time, loosing control over what he wrote and would have to re-enter the expression again later if he did a mistake. 

This is mimicking a physical 4 operators calculator with their limitation… It's a shame we're still there in 2011. Besides Mathematica that is very expensive and some couple of freewares, it's hard to find something that does math *normally* :)

Comment: Yes Dave. This kind! you should have told me before… ;-) But now I'm interested on making my stuff work. Thanks tho, I'll keep an eye on it :-).